# Check if the user has WRITE access to target folder using POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell

I have written a PowerShell script that could move the log files from the source (it'ss a VM) to a target (its a big Drive). 
For the above mentioned part I declare a **PsDrive** and move the log files using a Service Account. The Service account should have access to a particular Active Directory Group, only then it will have WRITE access (for moving the files).

Now, what I'm trying to achieve here is if by any chance the Service Account looses it's WRITE access, then I would like to send an alert to the ADMIN team regarding it. I'm aware of how to send an email alert.

Can someone tell me how to check if the Service Account has WRITE access before declaring the **PsDrive**?
If the Service Account does not have WRITE access then I would like to exit the code and move the log files. Below I have provided a part of my code.

```
##Use the available password files for creating PSDrives
$encrypted = Get-Content E:\servers\Disk_Space_Monitoring\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (1..16)
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("domain\username", $encrypted)
##Map the source and target links as power shell drives
New-PSDrive -Name TARGET -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\**.**.***.**\servers$\Backups\logfiles" -Credential $credential | Out-Null
New-PSDrive -Name SOURCE -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\admin_host.domain.com\servers$" -Credential $credential | Out-Null
```

PS: I would like to check if the service account has WRITE access to the **SOURCE**. **SOURCE** exists in the VM from which I'm executing the PowerShell script.

Comment: Why do you need to check before creating the PSDrive? Create the PSDrive, then (try to) create a dummy file and delete it. If that succeeds you have write access.

Comment: That easy! not sure why I didn't get his idea. So stupid to write such big question. Any way I will check and get back to you.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I applied your idea thanks it works:

    New-Item -Path "SOURCE:\" -Name "testfile.txt" -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a test file." | Out-Null
    New-Item -Path "TARGET:\$Server\" -Name "testfile.txt" -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a test file." | Out-Null
    If (Test-Path SOURCE:\testfile.txt)
      {
        If (Test-Path TARGET:\$Server\testfile.txt)
          {
             Code Block
           }
        }